# Urban Explorer teen novel with radiation symbol on the front cover

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

These kids were like urban explorers. I found the book during the years 2013–2014. So it must've been written before that.

This book was thick and had a picture of a fallout symbol on it, and that the book talked about teens in tunnels. I can't remember if it was about time travel, radiation, or something.

I remember there were a group of teens. They discovered something underground but had to be led there by secret underground tunnels.

I know it's not *City of Ember*, nor was it a really old book.

It looked like it had semi-new cover art. Perhaps the cover was a tunnel and a chain-linked fence with the nuclear radiation sign on it?

Comment: "Fallout symbol"? Like this? https://orau.org/health-physics-museum/collection/civil-defense/miscellaneous/fallout.html#:~:text=%22The%20shelter%20symbol%20on%20the,of%20the%20triangles%20pointing%20down.%22

Comment: @Valorum I believe that is the Fallout "Shelter" Symbol (Distinct triangles). A fallout symbol looks like: https://clipartcraft.com/images/fallout-logo-symbol-5.png (with curved outer edge) This is the same symbol for Radiation warnings.

Comment: Do you remember anymore of the story? Were the Teens on their own? Or were they a team of teens who's job was exploring for a larger group. Were they coming into contact with other groups? (peaceful trading/violently conflicts) Or mutated animals or plants? Or undead?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details. E.g., Is the setting post-apocalyptic? If so, what is the apocalyptic event? Are there any other sci-fi/fantasy aspects to the novel? For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Comment: @Valorum yes that's the symbol i remember. I get confused between the fallout shelter and nuclear symbol.

Comment: @NJohnny unfortunately no, i do remember there were a group of teens. They discovered something underground but had to be lead there by secret underground tunnels. No undead or mutated animals. It was kinda semi hard science maybe? It was so long ago